# How to pass user ID in Javascript function in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the current users ID and pass it as a variable into a javascript function (see "USER_ID_GOES_HERE"). Whats the best practice for doing so?

here is my function:

```
function hide_loading() {
Wild.onChartsReady(function() {
  var series = new Wild.Series("Viewed Post", {
    analysisType: "count",
    timeframe: "this_week",
    interval: "daily",
    groupBy: "title",
    filters: [{"property_name":"author","operator":"eq","property_value":'USER_ID_GOES_HERE'}]
  });
  series.draw(document.getElementById("mine"), { lineWidth: 2 });
});
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the user id first?

Comment: yeah isnt it this: <?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?> ... im just not sure how to incorporate that into the JS function. @AliGajani

Comment: Yeah just put that in.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in a PHP file, such as your theme's `functions.php`. I prefer to put it in a custom plugin.

```
function headcheese() { ?>
    <script type=”text/JavaScript”>
        var current_user_id = '<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'headcheese');
```

This puts the current user ID in a JavaScript global variable. So you can then use it in your `filters` array.

Comment: `"text/javaScript"` not ` ”text/JavaScript”`

Comment: also for anyone using this method make sure to defer ur script as ur code might execute before the above var is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
filters: [{"property_name":"author","operator":"eq","property_value":'USER_ID_GOES_HERE'}]
```

to

```
filters: [{"property_name":"author","operator":"eq","property_value":<?=get_current_user_id() ?>}]
```

Note: that this isn't secure for some applications, double check the user id server side.

Comment: Yeah, this assumes the JS file is either generated by a PHP script, or lives inside a PHP file. If your JS is in a separate .js file, this definitely will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `wp_localize_script`. Here is a good explanation of it:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/pass-php-variable-to-javascript

I don't want to reiterate everything in that post. Essentially, you will be passing php variables to the javascript via that function. The variables can then be retrieved from a parameters object within the javascript.